# JS For Loops Returning Empty Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, nested-loops

The `chooseRecipe` function should compare the arrays in `bakeryA` and `bakeryB` with the `ingredients` of each `recipe`. If `bakeryA` and `bakeryB` each have an ingredient for a recipe, then the name of the recipe should be printed. In this case, `Persian Cheesecake` is what should be printed. However, it keeps returning an empty array.

I understand that I'm starting off with an empty array, but shouldn't `suitableRecipe.push(recipes[i].name);` be taking care of that?

Would appreciate any guidance, or suggestions for a better way to do this.

```
let bakeryA = ['saffron', 'eggs', 'tomato paste', 'coconut', 'custard'];
let bakeryB = ['milk', 'butter', 'cream cheese'];
let recipes = [
    {
        name: 'Coconut Sponge Cake',
        ingredients: ['coconut', 'cake base']
    },
    {
        name: 'Persian Cheesecake',
        ingredients: ['saffron', 'cream cheese']
    },
    {
        name: 'Custard Surprise',
        ingredients: ['custard', 'ground beef']
    }
];

const chooseRecipe = function(bakeryA, bakeryB, recipes) {
  let suitableRecipe = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < recipes[i].ingredients.length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < bakeryA.length; k++) {
        if (bakeryA[k] === recipes[i].ingredients[j]) {
          for (let l = 0; l < bakeryB.length; l++) {
            for (let m = 0; m < recipes[i].ingredients; m++) {
              if (bakeryB[l] === recipes[i].ingredients[m]) {
                suitableRecipe.push(recipes[i].name);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return suitableRecipe;
}

console.log(chooseRecipe(bakeryA, bakeryB, recipes));
```

Comment: `for (let m = 0; m < recipes[i].ingredients; m++) {` is missing `.length` for `ingredients` ?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much cleaner way to do this, and it involves using [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Assuming that `bakeryA` and `bakeryB` list each ingredient once:

```js
let bakeryA = ['saffron', 'eggs', 'tomato paste', 'coconut', 'custard'];
let bakeryB = ['milk', 'butter', 'cream cheese'];
let recipes = [
    {
        name: 'Coconut Sponge Cake',
        ingredients: ['coconut', 'cake base']
    },
    {
        name: 'Persian Cheesecake',
        ingredients: ['saffron', 'cream cheese']
    },
    {
        name: 'Custard Surprise',
        ingredients: ['custard', 'ground beef']
    }
];

const chooseRecipe = function(bakeryA, bakeryB, recipes) {
  let aIngredients = new Set(bakeryA);
  let bIngredients = new Set(bakeryB);
  return recipes.filter(recipe => 
     recipe.ingredients.every(ingredient =>
         aIngredients.has(ingredient) || bIngredients.has(ingredient))
  );
}

console.log(chooseRecipe(bakeryA, bakeryB, recipes));
```

Some notes:

- [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) allows you to check if every ingredient in a recipe is in either `bakeryA` or `bakeryB`.
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to iterate over and filter out values that don't match that condition specified.

This approach is also more efficient, since it saves you from having to loop 5 (!) times, which will get very very slow as `bakeryA`, `bakeryB`, `ingredients` and `recipes` become larger and larger.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use handy array functions like filter, find and some for that kind of opperation. However if you simply want to know why your code doesn't work, there's an easy fix.

You are missing a .length in your innermost for loop. The correct loop is:

```
for (let m = 0; m < recipes[i].ingredients.length; m++) {
...
}
```

You coud make it way more concise by using the available array functionality. A solution could look like:

```
const choose = (bakeryA, bakeryB, recipes) => recipes.filter(
    ({ingredients}) => bakeryA.some(i => ingredients.includes(i)) && bakeryB.some(i => ingredients.includes(i))
);
```

Comment: Thank you! The fact I missed the .length really illustrates why looping like this is not a great idea. I'll look into using the filter function for this.